# how to solve this error in windows store app before submit it?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

TITLE="Debug configuration test" RATIONALE="The App should not install any debug binaries."
TEST INDEX="46" NAME="Debug configuration" DESCRIPTION="The App should not install any debug binaries." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:03s.43ms">

Comment: Change your build mode to Release.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store doesn't allow Debug builds; you just need to change the build configuration to Release.